# Vagrant not work and not respond error message

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I have installed Vagrant on Mac OS X 10.11 and it doesn't work. I have a file created from PuPHPet and when I run the `Vagrant Up` command it does nothing. The most curious thing is that if I run `Vagrant version` it doesn't answer anything either. The command is installed but does not answer any error message either.
I have virtualbox installed in version 6.0.18.
Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: can you run `which vagrant` and execute from full path - do you have any config on your terminal that will not output the error ?

Comment: If I run `wich vagrant` this is the result: `/usr/local/bin/vagrant`. I run `vagrant version` from full path and the result is the same, no message. I don't have any config on my terminal for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue. I tried below steps which help me to solve issue

- reinstall virtualbox
- run `brew install hashicorp/tap/hashicorp-vagrant` this command